# Android 4x2 widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

Looking at the Facebook widget I realized its a 4x2 cell and this isn't one of the standard sizes. I have tried to re-create a widget of this size (either as 320x200 or 294x146 px) however the widget doesn't look good on all devices. The widget layout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Portrait -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/widget"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_bg"
    >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/widget_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:textSize="20.0sp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
             />

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/widget_thumb"
            android:layout_width="304dip" 
            android:layout_height="90dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb_placeholder_large"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/widget_title"
            android:background="#000"
            />

    <!--  previous button -->
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/widget_previous"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/left_button"/>

    <!--  Next Button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/widget_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/right_button"  />


    <!-- Indicator -->

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/widget_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <!--  ProgressBar throws exception when it's set invisible from RemoteViews use a layout wrapper instead -->
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="15dp" 
            android:layout_height="15dp">
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

On the Motorola Droid this layout fits properly, however on other devices the ImageView sits way below. Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

The drawable_bg.png is 294x146px.

- Sandeep

Answer (score 1):

The actual size of the widget depends on

- the display resolution (pixels) of the device
- the used home application (they have different notification bars and bottom bars)
- the Android OS version (different versions also have different home apps)

So better make your layout "fill_parent" and your background image a "ninepatch" image.
Also use different background images for different display resolution (dpi) to make the background image look perfect.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should consider creating more layouts for different screen sizes , and test them so you could make sure your widget looks good on all screen sizes .